# permalink field not working in the basic Instagram API

Tags: php, instagram-api

When I am triggering the below URL then I got the error message in the response,

[https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username&access_token=[token]](https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,permalink,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username&access_token=%5Btoken%5D)

> **Response**:
> {
> "error": {
> "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
> "type": "OAuthException",
> "is_transient": true,
> "code": 2,
> "fbtrace_id": "A7NK5iyZc7KWjLRWuhZEGNA"
> }
> }

But when I remove the **permalink** field form the URL then I am getting the results.

[https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username&access_token=[token]](https://graph.instagram.com/me/media?fields=id,caption,media_type,media_url,thumbnail_url,timestamp,username&access_token=%5Btoken%5D)

> **Response:**
> {
> "data": [
> {
> "id": "17912377570308383",
> "media_type": "IMAGE",
> "media_url": "..",
> "timestamp": "2019-06-28T12:55:01+0000",
> "username": "testing.demo1"
> }
> ...
> },

So think the permalink field is not working due to some issues.

For your references, first link (**with permalink**) was worked at yesterday.

> **Doc Link of the fields**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media#fields

Comment: After some time, It is working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a general problem for all users using Instagram Basic API. We shall wait until it is solved on Facebook end.

Please follow the issue on support thread: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/935079356895648/

Comment: I think facebook team solve the issue, Now, permalink field is working from my end.